# elasticsearch aggs unqiue ip addresses

Tags: elasticsearch

Some indexes contains a field called `clientip` and I need to find unique IP address counts in specified range of timestamps. To achieve this;

Running query below;

```
GET /testbaguni-2020.10/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "clientip"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "hour_of_day": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['timestamp'].value.getHour()",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-10-05T18:18:10.063Z",
              "lte": "2020-10-13T18:18:10.063Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "1" : {
      "value" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

value of aggregations is 0, but there are many document in current index with that field..

```
GET /testbaguni-2020.10/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "fields.clientip":"127.0.0.1"
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.18232156,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testbaguni-2020.10",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tGgRHnUBYOJjF0gPoog3",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2020-10-12T21:25:20.7164826+03:00",
          "fields" : {
            "hour_of_day" : 21,
            "clientip" : "127.0.0.1",
... 
          }
        }
      },
```

INDEX MAPPING:

```
{
  "testbaguni-2020.10" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "exceptions" : {
          "properties" : {
            "ClassName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Depth" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "HResult" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "Message" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "RemoteStackIndex" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "Source" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "StackTraceString" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields" : {
          "properties" : {
            "ActionId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ActionName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ActionResult" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "AssemblyName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ContentLength" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "ContentType" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Controller" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "CreationTime" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "Destination" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ElapsedMilliseconds" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "EndpointName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Environment" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "EventId" : {
              "properties" : {
                "Id" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "Name" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "ExceptionDetail" : {
              "properties" : {
                "HResult" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "InnerException" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "Class" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "ClientConnectionId" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "Data" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "HelpLink" : {
                          "properties" : {
                            "BaseHelpUrl" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "EvtID" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "EvtSrc" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "LinkId" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            "ProdName" : {
                              "type" : "text",
                              "fields" : {
                                "keyword" : {
                                  "type" : "keyword",
                                  "ignore_above" : 256
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "ErrorCode" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "Errors" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "Class" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "LineNumber" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "Message" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "Number" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "Server" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "Source" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "State" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "HResult" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "InnerException" : {
                      "properties" : {
                        "ErrorCode" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "HResult" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "Message" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "NativeErrorCode" : {
                          "type" : "long"
                        },
                        "Type" : {
                          "type" : "text",
                          "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                              "type" : "keyword",
                              "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "LineNumber" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "Message" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "Number" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "Server" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "Source" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "State" : {
                      "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "Type" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Message" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Source" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Type" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "FullName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Host" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "HostingRequestFinishedLog" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "HostingRequestStartingLog" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "MachineName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Method" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "MethodInfo" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "OrderStatus" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ParentId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Path" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "PathBase" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "PhysicalPath" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Protocol" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "QueryString" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "RequestId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "RequestPath" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "RouteData" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Scheme" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "SourceContext" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "SpanId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "StatusCode" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "TraceId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ValidationState" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ViewName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "VirtualPath" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "clientip" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "hour_of_day" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "level" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "messageTemplate" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "renderings" : {
          "properties" : {
            "HostingRequestFinishedLog" : {
              "properties" : {
                "Format" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Rendering" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "HostingRequestStartingLog" : {
              "properties" : {
                "Format" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Rendering" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why it returns 0? Is there any way to debug DSL to find issues effect result ?

Comment: can you please share your sample index data and index mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used field name in wrong way. You are querying `cardinality` on `clientip` but you must do it on `fields.clientip`. Your `cardinality` query would be something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "fields.clientip"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is what I get if I do this; "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [fields.clientip] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."

Comment: This is because of your mapping on this field which is stored as `text`. As you know, you should set the type of this field to `keyword` or `ip`. setting `fielddata= true` can also be a solution but it uses more heap in calculations of elasticsearch. You cannot execute aggregations on `text` fields without setting `fielddata=true`.

Comment: it makes sense, can you tell me how to do that? I realize that it because posted from .net logger via serilog,

Comment: For achiving this, you need to define your mapping from scratch. then you need to reindex your data to this newly created index. set your mapping of this section as below:```{  "mappings": {"post":{ "properties":{ "fields":{"properties":{"clientip":{"type": "ip" }, "hour_of_day":{ "type": "integer" }}}}}}
}}``` . if your use elasticsearch version upper 7 please omit `post` section from the mapping.